# Modify date time format using php

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have to import some data from a csv file where the dates have been stored in the following format:

15/07/2019 11:16:13

I need to convert this to

2019-07-15 11:16:13

I tried

```
$time = strtotime($column [2]);
$column_2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time);
```

where $column [2] is the csv column where this data is held, but it just returned a date of 1970-01-01 01:00:00

When I echo $time it is empty, so I'm guessing strtotime doesn't work on the date time format I'm trying to use.

What is the correct method for doing this?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/zh/datetime.formats.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $column[2]);
$column_2 = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: this answer is correct, but does not explain the OP's error situation, just to clarify, it yields `1970-01-01 01:00:00` because the data input date is invalid to begin with. the correct american date format should be `m/d/Y` or `d.m.Y` european. thus strtotime fails. and since it will not be parsed by strtotime, the preferable way is to use and provide a custom format which `DateTime::createFromFormat` can provide

Comment: msg, Thanks for pointing me to DateTime::createFromFormat. Works perfectly now. @ghost thanks for the explanation as to why strtotime failed. Every day is a school day!